# replacing html syntax/ascii code in pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find a way to replace the html syntax within a string. I get a lot of csv files, so I found pandas to be an awesome tool to deal with csv.

Sometimes I receive data that has html syntax embedded in a string, for example in the address column, i see `125&#45128 downing st` , which is `125-128 downing st`. It's not only `&#49`, I also get `&#39` and `&amp`, which are `'` and `&`.

I tried to do this code, but I know it's not giving me the right format

```
df = df.replace(r'[&#45]','-', regex=True)
```

I get several columns such as business name, address, city, state - so I would like to target all columns just to make sure all the html syntax are removed/replaced

Dataframe format

```
    Address 1                   Company
0   1st&#452st Avenue N         johnson &amp johnson
1   243&#454800 Kingsway Ave    cold &amp brew 
2   300 Hwy 7                   coder&#39s club
```

Desired format

```
    Address 1                   Company
0   1st-2st Avenue N            johnson and johnson
1   243-4800 Kingsway Ave       cold and brew 
2   300 Hwy 7                   coder's club
```

I'm a newbie to pandas, but so I far I love this tool.  Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:

Ok, I found my mistake on the code I use, this `df = df.replace(r'[&#45]','-', regex=True)` should be `df = df.replace(r'&#45','-', regex=True)`; this will replace that html syntax. However I still would like to find a pythonic solution to this problem.

I am tempted to do this code in order to remove the other html syntax.

```
df = df.replace(r'&#45','-', regex=True).replace(r'&#39','', regex=True).replace(r'&amp','and', regex=True)
```

is there a clean solution to this line of code?

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. I think you can change the values by lists. For example `df.replace([r'&#45', r'&#39'], ['-', ''], regex=True)`, but I am not sure. Check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: @gabra no problem and thanks for the suggestion about the edit.  Yes, the code provided in the first comment worked like a charm, this is what I need, trying to be a better python coder.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to leave an answer to new people coming here, a possible solution, as discussed on the comments, is:

```
df.replace([r'&#45', r'&#39', r'&amp'], ['-', '', 'and'], regex=True)
```

or

```
df.replace({'&#45':'-', r'&#39':'', '&amp':'and'}, regex=True)
```